# Partial fit with tslearn clustering methods

Tags: python, time-series, clustering, training

Is there a way to use `partial_fit` with `tslearn` clustering methods like [`TimeSeriesKMeans`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html#tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans)? I have a large dataset and would like to train the model incrementally. If this method is not available, can we use [`get_params`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html#tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.get_params) and [`set_params`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html#tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.get_params) to accomplish this?